# AWS CDK NetworkLoadBalancer - add target group (add_targets) fails with target.attachToNetworkTargetGroup is not a function

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Basically I'm trying to get an nlb (network load balancer) to point to a alb (application load balancer) but cdk fails at the `.add_targets` call with the error `jsii.errors.JSIIError: target.attachToNetworkTargetGroup is not a function`

Here's a snippet of my cdk:

```py
    nlb = elbv2.NetworkLoadBalancer(
        stack,
        id="nlb",
        load_balancer_name="my-nlb",
        vpc=vpc,
    )
    
    cert = elbv2.ListenerCertificate.from_arn(certificate_arn)
    
    listener_80 = nlb.add_listener("listener", port=80)
    
    alb_target_group = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
        stack,
        id="alb_target_group",
        target_type=elbv2.TargetType.ALB,
        protocol=elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
        vpc=vpc,
    )
    
    listener_80.add_targets(id="target", port=80, targets=[alb_target_group])
```

I get the following error and it's due to the call to

`listener_80.add_targets(id="target", port=80, targets=[alb_target_group])`

````sh
    cdk diff --app "python3 fargate.py"
    cluster sec group  <class 'NoneType'>
    connections  <aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Connections object at 0x10c0c91f0>
    jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
      TypeError: target.attachToNetworkTargetGroup is not a function
          at NetworkTargetGroup.addTarget (/private/var/folders/v0/6bvb2_m975jd380hx464rtzm0000gq/T/
    jsii-kernel-wnPJIQ/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/
    aws-elasticloadbalancingv2/lib/nlb/network-target-group.js:1:1547)```
    
    TypeError: target.attachToNetworkTargetGroup is not a function
````

I'm using
`cdk version 2.20.0` and
`python v 3.8.0` and
`aws-cli/2.3.4`

Any idea why I'm getting the
`TypeError: target.attachToNetworkTargetGroup is not a function` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.add_targets` and `.add_target_group` are different, and in your scenario, you should use `.add_target_group`.

By the way, in AWS CDK, the constants and classes for ALB and NLB are different.

If your architecture is

1. Crete a network load balancer
2. Add a listener for port 80
3. Create a target group which target type is ALB
4. Attach the target group to the listener

Your snippet would be:

```py
    nlb = elbv2.NetworkLoadBalancer(
        stack,
        id="nlb",
        load_balancer_name="my-nlb",
        vpc=vpc,
    )
    
    listener_80 = nlb.add_listener("listener", port=80)
    
    alb_target_group = elbv2.NetworkTargetGroup(
        stack,
        id="alb_target_group",
        target_type=elbv2.TargetType.ALB,
        protocol=elbv2.Protocol.TCP,
        vpc=vpc,
    )
    
    listener_80.add_target_group("target", alb_target_group)
```